# SubmitChanges doesn't always update database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 (.NET framework 4.5) with LINQ-to-SQL and SQL Server 2008 R2

This function returns always true if I run it through debug mode, but when I run it without debug, it returns false. I once got this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUOOs.png

I tried googling this, some similiar problems came up but I checked them all:

- UserProfiles table has a primary key
- The datacontext is in sync with the database
- I've tried putting **ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict** as an argument in SubmitChanges()
- I've tried to put above the facebookID in LINQ designer: **UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never**

Nothing works. I have never experienced anything like this before. Does anyone have any idea?

**Code:**

*facebookID field in SQL Server is varchar(50) NULL with default value NULL*

```
public static bool changeFacebookIDByEmail(string email, string facebookID)
{
    UserProfile profile = (from s in _dc.Users
                           join u in _dc.Memberships on s.UserId equals u.UserId
                           join i in _dc.UserProfiles on u.UserId equals i.userID
                           where u.Email == email
                           select i).SingleOrDefault();

    profile.facebookID = facebookID;

    ChangeSet cs = _dc.GetChangeSet();

    _dc.SubmitChanges();

    if (cs.Updates.Count <= 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: When it returns false, did the facebookID change? How did you check if it did or did not change? What SQL is showing um in SQL Profiler? Do you change other data with the same SubmitChanges call?

Comment: No, when it returns false, it does not change, so the ChangeSet works. I check if it changes or not with the ChangeSet above, then return true/false according to that. No I only change one field, that's the facebookID and that's what the function's purpose is. But the ChangeConflictException in the image above puzzles me, because the only possible conflict would be that I update the database before in SQL Management Studio, just to reset the facebookID - before running the code. I have not yet checked in SQL Profiler, maybe that's the next step.

Comment: When you run it without debug, the facebookID must not have changed (correct?). Why would it not change? Print it out to the response or a file. Are you using a DataContext per request?

Comment: When I run it without debug, the facebookID doesn't change, correct. I think this has something to do with SQL Server locking the row in the database, because before running the code without debug I always run the following SQL statement to reset the facebookID for the user, for testing purpose: UPDATE UserProfiles SET facebookID = NULL WHERE userID = '85A6D951-15C8-4892-B17D-BD93F3D0ACBB'

Comment: You said DataContext and DB are in sync, but when you execute a manual SQL statement they probably aren't in sync. Can you check if that is the case? What makes you sure they are in sync?

Comment: I meant DataContext and DB are in sync, schema-wise. The fields and options on each field are the same.

Comment: I had this issue with a simple update in a View, but if i changed the LINQ to update the table directly, it work !!!! Don't know why !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are executing a manual SQL statement:

```
UPDATE UserProfiles SET facebookID = NULL WHERE userID = '85A6D951-15C8-4892-B17D-BD93F3D0ACBB'
```

This will set the `facebookID` to null. Entity framework does not know this, though. It cannot interpret raw SQL. So it still thinks the `facebookID` is set to some value. When you later set it to that value in `changeFacebookIDByEmail` EF thinks nothing changed.

Sou you probably should not execute raw SQL strings. Use EF to change the value to null.

Comment: This sounds like a valid reason. But I cannot execute raw SQL? How would you go about using EF to change the value to null (quick method) so I can test the function again? Also why does it work in debug mode?

Comment: 1) you can execute raw SQL but you must be careful to keep the loaded entities synchronized (hard). 2) Just assign null to `profile.facebookID` (is there a reason that wouldn't work in your case?) 3) I don't know. Either a conditional depending on Debugger.IsAttached or a timing issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have never had any problem with anything like this before. But next time I will just go through the context. Thank you for your answer. I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change .singleordefault to .single I think your problem will be revealed pretty soon after that.

Basically anything found by your query with be in the datacontext. Anything new eg default will not.

You need to rewrite your routine to insert the new user in the case where it's not found.

**EDIT**

This is some code from a project I have been working on. I've cut out a bunch of stuff to demonstrate how it should work.

```
// add the identity as necessary
var found = dB.Identities.SingleOrDefault(q => q.UserName == userName);

if (found == null)
{
    found = new Identity
    {
        Domain = domain,
        Password = User.Identity.AuthenticationType,
        Salt = "",
        UserName = userName,
        LastUpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now
    };

    dB.Identities.InsertOnSubmit(found);
}



dB.SubmitChanges(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. But it's rather weird that the record is found in debug mode but not in non-debug mode. :)

Comment: Thank you, but the record DOES exist. It's just because I recently updated the database with raw SQL and the EF doesn't know the record has changed. See answer above.

Comment: I thought you said you were using Linq 2 sql not EF. anyway I'm glad you have a solution.